# How to limit the number of cells per table row to 3?

Tags: php, css, smarty

I have a dynamically filled table, in which I would like to limit the number of columns to 3, so that the next `td` stars on the next line.  (See http://kbay.in and check the categories button at the top of the page.)

Here's how I import the data using Smarty PHP:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4" width="100"; border-collapse="collapse";>
<tr>

{foreach from=$array_categories item=v name=cat}
<td valign="top" width="116px" align="left">
{capture name=some_content assign=categ_url}
{if $v.subcats>0}{$live_site}/{if $seo_settings.enable_mod_rewrite}{$v.id}-{$v.url_title}/1/listings.html{else}listings.php?category={$v.id}{/if}{/if}
{/capture}

                <a href="{$categ_url}">{$v.name|escape:"html"}{if $appearance.categ_count_ads} ({$v.ads}) {/if}</a>  


{/foreach}</td></tr> </table>
```

How can I make it so that there are only 3 table cells in each row?

Comment: @ajreal: Although it does appear to be tabular data? Each row (of 3 columns) needs to be contained in a `<tr>`..`</tr>` - you seem to imply otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`iteration`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl#foreach.property.iteration) property of `foreach` loop:

```
...
{foreach from=$array_categories item=v name=cat}
{if $smarty.foreach.cat.iteration % 3 == 0 && $smarty.foreach.cat.iteration > 0}
</tr>
<tr>
{/if}
<td valign="top" width="116px" align="left">
...
```

`$smarty.foreach.cat.iteration` is Smarty2 syntax, if you use Smarty3 you can also use `$v@iteration`.

Answer (score 0):

increment a counter each time in the loop and do a check within your loop starting a new row when necessary. Something like:

```
if ($counter % 3 == 0) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
}
```

Comment: </tr><tr>      or       <tr></tr>

Comment: `</tr><tr>`, you want to end current row and start a new one

Comment: @majid: This may be obvious, but it is worth noting that (0 % 3 == 0) is true, so you need to avoid or handle this condition.